# Magento check if product has custom option and show text next to price

Tags: php, magento

I want to check if a product has a custom option applied if it does I want to add "/ half metre" after the price and if it does'tn I want it to say "/ m" how can I do this. What file should I edit? I'm using magento 1.9.2

See example product [example product](http://viewingcloud.co.uk/888999/faux-fur/two-toned-faux-fur/two-toned-faux-fur-alaska-fox)

Answer (score 0):

Just switch on path hints (http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints)
and look for template which renders price section. In my case it's frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog/product/price.phtml

[image]

Then add something like

```
. $_product->getCustomAttribute() == true ? "/ half metre" : ""
```

To the place where

```
 echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price ...
```

located.

Hope it helps.